# Visual Studio 2010 C++/CLI in Static Library Mode: could not find assembly 'mscorlib.dll'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, c++-cli, 64-bit

I am working on a C++/CLI project with VS 2012 in Dynamic Library (.dll) and x64 mode.

If I switch the mode to Static Library, I get the error below.

**Error 1   error C1107: could not find assembly 'mscorlib.dll': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable   C:\Depot\Main\Current\Sln\ALibraryProject\Stdafx.cpp    1   1   ALibraryProject**

I tried removing the reference to the mscorlib.dll then adding it again from:

Project > Properties > General > Common Properties

But that didn't help. As I know that VS handles the reference to the .NET assemblies, I don't want to add a disk file reference to it as it seems illogical! Did anybody face this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I switch the mode to Static Library

This is not the typical error you get when you try to build a static library with /clr in effect.  I'd have to assume you've been tinkering with project settings to get rid of the inscrutable linker errors you get when you try to do this.

Core issue is that the C++/CLI build system doesn't support static libraries that contain MSIL.  Managed code doesn't use a linker, binding happens at runtime.  Which makes the essential difference between static libraries and DLLs disappear.  So Microsoft decided to not support it because it didn't make much sense to implement it.  Unfortunately they don't yell loud enough when you try to do it anyway, the linker errors you get don't give enough of a hint what you did wrong.  Workarounds, like merging with ILMerge don't work either, it cannot deal with mixed-mode assemblies.  Merging the native code sections and their associated relocation table entries is very untrivial.

Keep in mind that it is fine to link native static libraries.  A typical C++/CLI project has only the ref class wrappers that need to be built with /clr in effect.  You can glue any amount of native code from libraries into the final assembly.

---

I'm forced to theorize about the actual compile error, too many programmers get this error for *another* reason that doesn't have anything to do with building static libraries and they are harassing me in the comments.

Do beware that targeting a different version of .NET than the one you have installed on your machine is quite a hazardous affair, particularly so if you want to target 4.0 and you have 4.5.x installed.  The key element in your .vcxproj file is the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>`.  This will be missing if you started the project targeting an old .NET version, you have to insert it yourself.  The IDE also doesn't support changing it if it *is* present, again edit by hand.

Which is enough to coax MSBuild into generating the proper compile command.  You can verify if that panned-out well, look in the *.tlog subdirectory of the Debug build directory for your project.  The cl.command.1.tlog file shows the options that were passed to the compiler.  It should contain:

> /AI"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0"
>   /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll"

Note the subdirectory, very important that it matches your intended .NET target.  v4.0 in this example.  And very, very important that it does *not* point to c:\windows\microsoft.net, the legacy location for reference assemblies.

Comment: that could'nt be farther from reality. Its actually very EASY to merge assemblies with native code (although not really recommended)  - i've done it several times, in fact part of my WORK includes native code in CLR-assemblies - but merging them left me with adding another build-step which i wanted to avoid ... so i chose the traditional way of referencing each assembly seperately.

Comment: ... and the part about C++/CLI being an "interop language" doesnt make any sense. Methinks you need to do a bit of research of your chosen topics. (Microsoft) Interop has NOTHING to do with language-specifics themselves, there cant be any "interop language" - interop is somewhat of a BRIDGE BETWEEN LANGUAGES. Please dont state your assumptions & fantasies like they're hard facts ...

Comment: You are ranting.  Post an answer instead.

Comment: downvoted, this does not answer the OP's question. For the solution see @link1305's answer.

Comment: The OP tried to build a static library.  This post answers his question.  @link's answer covers another kind of problem, a pretty nasty one indeed, but doesn't have anything to do with the OP's issue.

Comment: Nice update. I'm removing the downvote and changing to upvote :)

Comment: Very late commenting on this but I had no problem compiling a managed C++ static library and linking with an unmanaged executable using link1305's answer in VS2012.

I had exactly the same error as in the question but the answer that managed C++ cannot be used in static libraries appears to be simply incorrect.

I haven't downvoted as it may have been true for past versions of VC++.

Answer (score 44):

I had the same problem when converting my solution from the VS2010 compiler to VS2013 compiler.

I resolved it by changing the project settings (for the project containing the managed .cpp file that was throwing this error) as follows:  In *Project Settings | C/C++ | General | Additional #using Directories* I added the macro **$(FrameworkPathOverride)**.  This resolves to the reference assembly directory for the version of .NET that you're targeting, which in my case is C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1

Comment: The same thing happened to me when upgrading from VS2010 to VS2015. I'm not sure why the **Win32** configuration had **$(FrameworkPathOverride)** already, but I had to add it to the **x64** configuration.

Comment: I used the macro **$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath64)** in VS2022 and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. Having a dll doesn't work, as I need to provide a native C++ wrapper for a .net object so it can fulfil a natice c++ interface -  I can't use .net in a dll interface - this gives a compile error

This worked as a static library in VS 2010 (with .net 4)

Some of my executables and dlls which also have some code with /clr. They don't have an issue. I'm not trying to make a net Lbirary.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing dependency in old and not updated mixed lib, which was also configured only in Debug configuration, and as result, it started to get the same error as yours after I changed some code.

It was not simple to find it, because error is not clear, and the dependency was set up via "Additional Dependencies" in project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Open visual studio and unload your project then Go to the project folder and open file .vcxproj . Search for tag "targetFrameworkVersion"
(if not present it means ur project is not using dot net frameworks.so no requirement of change)
Change it to required version
Save the file.
And now reload the project .