# Visual Studio C++ 2010 Error

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a problem, I've installed Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express and whenever I make a new project then run the debug to test it it gives me the following error:

```
Error   2   error C1107: could not find assembly 'mscorlib.dll': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable   c:\Users\Cretu\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test2\test2\stdafx.cpp 1
```

Leaving this aside, when I close Visual C++ and open it and then try to open my project it gives me this error:

```
The Visual C++ project "test2" is targeting ".NETFramework, Version=v4.0", which is not installed on this machine. You must download this framework in order to open...
```

But I already have installed the following .NETFrameworks on my machine (Control Panel -> Installed Programs, that's where i got their name):

```
Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1,
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile,
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended.
```

Can somebody please explain why this is happening? I've already re-installed .NET Framework 4.0 and rebooted my PC but I still get this error. Please help. Thanks in advance for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Note that you appear to have created a C++/CLI (.Net-based) project. That is _not_ the same as C++. Also, a standard C++ project would not be producing the error.

Comment: Have you Tried looking at [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135490/visual-studio-2010-c-cli-in-static-library-mode-could-not-find-assembly-msco

Comment: Well, when I click new project I only have a Visual C++ window with 3 sub-groups: CLR, Win32 and General. And then I choose from CLR Windows Forms Applications but it give me that error.

Comment: There are numerous tutorials on the Net for what you are trying to do. Googling will no doubt produce step-by-step instructions. And what you want is a Win32 project, not CLR = Common Language Runtime = .Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quite a few packages. Im guessing you tried to install .NET manually - well that never works, you need to use an [official installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851), heres my list of working .NET 4 and 4.5, im guessing the "Chart Controls" are actually unnecessary :

[image: .NET installation-details]

Comment: I installed .NET Framework beside 4.0 and 1.1 and when i rebooted the computer suddenly .NET Framework 4.0 disappears from the list and 4.5 appears. So I got left with 4.5 and 1.1, what happened?

Comment: 4.0 got updated and fixed, apparently. If it still doesnt work you willl have to uninstall, reboot and reinstall. Something went horribly wrong the first time you tried to manually install.

Comment: Now I no longer get those errors, but I do get another error when I try to run the program: "Error 1 error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt c:\Users\Cretu\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Hello World\Hello World\LINK
"

Comment: create a new solution.